# Python Pandas: How can I check the data types of tuple values in a list?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list which has tuples inside. The tuples have 4 values inside, and I need to check the 4th value of tuples.

For instance:

```
list_tuples = [(a,b,c,2),(c,d,s,3),(k,l,m,5)]
```

Here for instance the 4th values are integer.

I have tried:

```
print(type(list_tuples[1][4]))
```

to reach the forth value of the first tuple, but it does not work.

Comment: Indexing starts at 0.

Comment: The fourth value is at index 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your tuple to this

```
list_tuples = [('a','b','c',2),('c','d','s',3),('k','l','m',5)]
print(type(list_tuples[1][3]))
```

Because it starts from 0 and it goes to 3 to pick 4th.

Answer (score 1):

In python (as in most programming languages) indexing is starting from zero.

To access the first element of the list: `list_tuples[0]` which is a tuple. To access it's forth element: `list_tuples[0][3]`

So you actually wants

```py
print(type(list_tuples[0][3]))
```

You accessed to [4] it's actually the fifth element which does not exist, hence an error